# i need helpp with a text pad

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image as background for a text pad and I want to make the background transparent without making the text transparent. I also have a hovering effect where the pad is transparent and then it appears when I hover my mouse over.

I can't wrap my head around this. I want the image in the background be more tranparent without the text

```css
.text-pad1 {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #191970;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(despremine.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  bottom: 830px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-pad-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-pad1" id="text-pad1">
      <p1>Nume: Nechifor Rareș <br><br> Nascut: 23 Octombrie 2004</p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```